# Is there any good tool for working on Database apart from Toad which requires license and DBVisualiser not supportive

Tags: sql, database

Is there any good tool for working on Dabtabase apart from Toad which requires license and DBVisualiser not supportive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fabForce Database Designer; it is GPL too.
http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/

Answer (score 1):

i'd recommend oracle SQLdeveloper. it has all the functionality you need for developing and maintanice

Answer (score 0):

I am using the free version of [WinSQL](http://www.synametrics.com/SynametricsWebApp/WinSQL.jsp).
I am also looking at [SQLDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) from Oracle.  I have heard it mentionned in the same breath as Toad.
In a pinch, I find that Microsoft Query, which comes with Excel, is more than adequate.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used Golden 32 from Benthic - it's simple, cheap, and has the most common features I need (queries, viewing relationships, editing data). It's Oracle only. Aqua Data Studio from AquaFold is another option that supports multiple databases and has a ton of features, but it much more expensive. I used it for a while but kept going back to Golden because of how fast and easy to use it was.

Answer (score 0):

I find SQuirrel SQL Client is an excellent tool.  It requires Java so depending on how you feel about that it may be a good thing or a bad thing.  I find it's nice because I work on Windows, Linux and OS X and it works great on all platforms.  If you work only on one platform you might be able to find better clients for that particular platform.

It has plug-ins for a lot of different databases, allows in table editing, has a data modelling module,  auto-completion in the SQL editor and lots of other nifty features.

http://www.squirrelsql.org/

SQuirrel is currently released under GNU Lesser General Public License.